# Does the Live CD allow saving downloaded apps and settings?

Tags: live-cd

I run Ubuntu from Live CD and want to retain settings and downloaded apps from the session. Does Ubuntu allow a configuration file similar to Puppy Linux that can be saved to the system's hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this on the Ubuntu wiki : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence.

I believe that it will allow you to do what you want.

Here is one for USB sticks: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent